# top border on FrameLayout when using tabs

Tags: android, tabs, border, tabwidget, android-framelayout

I have a screen that uses tabs in my android application. There is a line (like a border) that shows between the tabwidget and the framelayout. I want to get rid of that line, but cant seem to find what it is. I have determined that it is part of the FrameLayout by setting its visibilty to gone. Please refer to the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    android:background="#fb8c10"
    >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_confirm_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/confirm_header"                 
    />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:background="#fb8c10"                              
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"                         
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
        android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"                                                
         />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is a link of the current layout and what I'm trying to do
http://img441.imageshack.us/g/screenshot20110116at513.png/

The orange layout is my app, and the gray is what I'm trying to do.

Notice how in the gray screenshot the tab flows into the frame.

Apologies for the links, I can't post images yet :p

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by manipulating the z-index using relative layout. I was able to position the tabs slightly over the frame layout. Refer to code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:background="#fb8c10"
        >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_confirm_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_header"

        />
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget77"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >                    
            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"                             
            android:layout_marginTop="33dip"                                                   
             />
             <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:background="#fb8c10"                              
            android:tabStripEnabled="true"  
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"                                            
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just now I came across this issue. However, I also tried to remove the top border of FrameLayout. I did it. but I don't think it is a way to remove the top border. anyway FYI,

Just place an TextView with background white on Border and use AbsoluteLayout.

Eg:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>

<TabHost 
    android:layout_x="0dip"
    android:layout_y="5dip" ...>

    <AbsoluteLayout android:padding="5dip" android:background="#ffffff">
        <TabWidget/>
        <FrameLayout ....
        android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="65dip" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</TabHost>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25dip" 
    android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="65dip" 
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't like using absolute positioning because I target multiple screen sizes. I was able to solve this, however, i will post the code above